# How to use Json passing by hiddenfield to replace the way of using viewstate in GridView in ASP web form

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

My project is ASP web forms, and I recently hope to use json.net to replace the viewstate which I use in gridview, like following:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDataForm
{
    public string LocationCode { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNo { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PdfURL { get; set; }
    public string Memos { get; set; }
}

public List<MyDataForm> MyDataList { set { ViewState["MyDataList"] = value; } get { return ViewState["MyDataList"] as List<MyDataForm>; } }

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = MyDataList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I hope to store the data in HiddenField, and then  catch the data back via this when post back each time:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataForm>( $("#hiddenFieldID").val())`

The main problem is come from when to replace viewstate in ASP page life cycle. 
In which Asp page life cycle stage, like Page_init, the gridview will call databind(), and if I can put the data which deserialize by Json in datasource, 
and then I think it can replace viewstate completely, is anyone know how to make that, thanks a lot.

Comment: is it windows or web forms? The question is not clear

Comment: You cannot "replace" ViewState yourself. That will cause errors. And you do not need to store the data in a HiddenField. ViewState will save the data for you so it is available on PostBack.

Comment: i think it can be done. just need some more clarify method to improve the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing many research, I found there is no way to using Json passing by hiddenfield to replace ViewState using in gridview. The main reason is the hiddenfield in ASP is not designed to send mass data.So, once the data is big enough, it will be slow down, no matter what library I use to parsing string in hiddenfield.